# how to find the client address in c using socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I have written the code like this after the `accept` function

```
getpeername(rs,(struct sockaddr *)&clentaddr,&len);
```

then after printing it the client address is showing as `0.0.0.0`

can u please try to assist me

Comment: How are you printing it? What's the definition of clentaddr and len? This is not enough code to make the call on what you've done wrong.

Comment: Did you initialize len=sizeof(sockaddr_in) ?  (I'm assuming clientaddr is of type sockaddr_in as well).

Comment: @selbie `sizeof(sockaddr_storage)` would be better...

Comment: Can you please add the lines before getpeername? How are rs, clentaddr and len declared and initialized?

Comment: struct sockaddr_in clentaddr  int len

Comment: int rs rs=accept(fd,0,0) fd is nothing but the value after returned from the creation of socket

Answer (score 1):

`rs` must be the listening socket if it is shown as bound to `0.0.0.0`. Try calling it on the socket *returned* by `accept()`.

Answer (score 0):

`accept()` returns the client's address in the structure referred to as `accept()`'s second parameter.

It is guaranteed to do this only if no error occurrs, so it is always a good idea to check a system call's return value.

Answer (score 0):

```
int accept(int s,
   struct sockaddr *addr,
   int *addrlen);
```

Here in above definition addr stores the address of the incoming connection

```
addr:-
The socket address of the connecting client that is filled in by accept 
before it returns. The format of addr is determined by the domain in which 
the client resides. This parameter can be NULL if the caller is not interested 
in the address of the client. If the addr parameter is not NULL, it points to
 a sockaddr structure.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char IPAddress[16] = {0};
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr, IPChar, sizeof IPAddress);

printf("The source is %s.\n", IPAddress);
```

Try out this code

Comment: rajesh i have tried by using this code also then also it is getting the output as 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Similar to RAJESH's answer, we can make use of the `inet_ntop` function described at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/inet_ntop.3.html. The part missing in the other answer is that the entire `sin_addr` must be casted to a `struct inaddr *` instead of actually accessing the `s_addr` member.

```
char clntIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET, (struct inaddr *)&clntAddr.sin_addr,clntIP,sizeof(clntIP));
printf("client IP is %s\n",clntIP);
```

Make sure you also `#include <arpa/inet.h>` in your file.